# Accessing Items in a Collection from a Class

Tags: vba, excel, vb6

-EDIT Fixed
I was missing one thing and doing one thing wrong. First I was missing a function to access the collection by index. And I should of been using a for Loop instead of a for each loop in my module code

I forgot to add this to the collection class

```
Public Function GetPayRecords(ByVal index As Variant) As PayRecords
      Set GetPayRecords = pObjCol.item(index)
End Function
```

and replaced

```
For Each vItem In .GetPayRecords
    ....code to do stuff    
Next vItem
```

with this in the module

```
Dim x As Integer
For x = 1 To .Count
    Debug.Print .GetPayRecords(x).PY_PayRecord.CEOCompanyID
    Debug.Print .GetPayRecords(x).PY_PayRecord.OrigBankID
Next x
```

I'm writing a program that has 8 Classes. Each class represents a specific record type.
I have an overall Class that contains those 8 classes which is for simplicity when coding in the Module. I only have to declare one class which gives me access to all 8 classes.  I have a collection which contains all the records types. Once all the logic of loading the individual records is complete they get added to the collection.  This all works perfectly and I can see all the records in the collection.  The final step, which happens to be where i'm having the problem, I need to extract each item within the collection by record type and write it to a csv. The problem I encounter is trying to iterate through each record.

Here's how the structure looks

#### Classes

- clsAllRecordTypes

  - clsRecordType1
  - clsRecordType2
  - ...
  - clsRecordType8

#### Collection

- clsColRecords

> The problem is in the retrieval

#### Module

```
    Dim PayRecord As PayRecords 'Class of Classes
    Dim PayRecordList As bankCollection 

    ...code to load all the payrecords

    With payrecordlist
         Foreach vItem in .pObjCol

               debug.print .pObjCol.Item(?) ' not sure why i can't see all 8 

         next vItem
    End With
```

When I add vItem to the watch I can see each and every record type filled up with information but yet i Can not access it.  Below is the Class of classes and collection

### Class of Classes

Option Explicit

```
'This class is a representation of all the record types that apply to our Payment Manager
'It aggregates all the record types (classes) into one class.  That one class is used in the main processing module for simplicty
'
Private pPayRecord As New PayRecord
Private pPNAR_OP As New PNAR_OP
Private pPNAR_RP As New PNAR_RP
Private pSuppACHREC As New SuppACHRec
Private pSuppCCRRec As New SuppCCRRec
Private pSuppCHKRec As New SuppCHKRec
Private pDocumentDelieveryRec As New DocumentDeliveryRecord
Private pInvoiceRecords As New InvoiceRecords

Public Property Get PY_PayRecord() As PayRecord
    Set PY_PayRecord = pPayRecord
End Property
Public Property Let PY_PayRecord(ByVal newPayRecord As PayRecord)
    Set pPayRecord = newPayRecord
End Property

Public Property Get PA_PNAR_OP() As PNAR_OP
    Set PA_PNAR_OP = pPNAR_OP
End Property
Public Property Let PA_PNAR_OP(ByVal newPNAR_OP_Record As PNAR_OP)
    Set pPNAR_OP = newPNAR_OP_Record
End Property

Public Property Get PA_PNAR_RP() As PNAR_RP
    Set PA_PNAR_RP = pPNAR_RP
End Property
Public Property Let PA_PNAR_RP(ByVal newPNAR_RP_Record As PNAR_RP)
    Set pPNAR_RP = newPNAR_RP_Record
End Property

Public Property Get AC_SuppACH() As SuppACHRec
    Set AC_SuppACH = pSuppACHREC
End Property
Public Property Let AC_SuppACH(ByVal newSuppACH_Record As SuppACHRec)
    Set pSuppACHREC = newSuppACH_Record
End Property

Public Property Get AC_SuppCCR() As SuppCCRRec
    Set AC_SuppCCR = pSuppCCRRec
End Property
Public Property Let AC_SuppCCR(ByVal newSuppCCR_Record As SuppCCRRec)
    Set pSuppCCRRec = newSuppCCR_Record
End Property

Public Property Get AC_SuppCHK() As SuppCHKRec
    Set AC_SuppCHK = pSuppCHKRec
End Property
Public Property Let AC_SuppCHK(ByVal newSuppCHK_Record As SuppCHKRec)
    Set pSuppCHKRec = newSuppCHK_Record
End Property

Public Property Get DocumentDeliveryRecord() As DocumentDeliveryRecord
    Set DocumentDeliveryRecord = pDocumentDelieveryRec
End Property
Public Property Let DocumentDeliveryRecord(ByVal newDocumentDeliveryRecord As DocumentDeliveryRecord)
    Set pDocumentDelieveryRec = newDocumentDeliveryRecord
End Property

Public Property Get InvoiceRecords() As InvoiceRecords
    Set InvoiceRecords = pInvoiceRecords
End Property
Public Property Let InvoiceRecords(ByVal newInvoiceRecord As InvoiceRecords)
    Set pInvoiceRecords = newInvoiceRecord
End Property
```

### Collection Class

```
Option Explicit
Private pHeaderRec As New HeaderRec
Private pNewPayRecords As New PayRecords
Public pObjCol As Collection
Private pTrailerRec As New TrailerRec

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set pObjCol = New Collection
End Sub
Private Sub Class_Terminate()
    Set pObjCol = Nothing
End Sub

Public Property Get HD_HeaderRecord() As HeaderRec
    Set HD_HeaderRecord = pHeaderRec
End Property
Public Property Let HD_HeaderRecord(ByVal newHeaderRecord As HeaderRec)
    Set pHeaderRec = newHeaderRecord
End Property

Sub Add(ByVal newPayRecs As PayRecords)
    pObjCol.Add newPayRecs
End Sub
Property Get Count() As Long
    Count = pObjCol.Count
End Property

Public Property Get TR_TrailerRecord() As TrailerRec
    Set TR_TrailerRecord = pTrailerRec
End Property
Public Property Let TR_TrailerRecord(ByVal newTrailer_Record As TrailerRec)
    Set pTrailerRec = newTrailer_Record
End Property
```

Comment: In your loop `vItem` should be set to an instance of `PayRecords`. What do you want to do with that instance?

Comment: I need to select each record type, then select each field within that selected record type.  Not sure if there's a better way to do this.  I'm thinking I may need to create a procedure in my Collection class to extract out each item.  Similar to a GET for a property in a class. The difference is I have 8 classes and within each class is 20 properties.  So I have to get the first class than get all the properties. Get the next class, get all the properties. Just have to figure out how to loop that.

Comment: As your code is structured right now, you'll need to individually address each class instance of each `PayRecords` instance (and each of their "sub-properties")  I'm not sure how else you'd do it and still be able to make use of the property values: presumably you need to do something specific with each specific record type and its properties? Hard to suggest something else without much more detail.

Comment: What is the purpose of `PayRecords`?  Your post is confusing because you use different names at different points.  Is your collection class `clsColRecords` or `bankCollection`?  Plus you are not stating what error you are getting.

Comment: [link]http://imgur.com/a/0BYK9  (1st pic) All the highlighted classes are record types. Which are all represented inside "Payrecords" class which the code for is above in my initial post.  Then the collection is where, once payrecords is filled it gets added into the collection.  The second picture is a filled collection with 732 Items, each item is a "Payrecords" which is made up of the previous pictures highlighted classes and each of those classes has between 20 - 30 fields. How do i loop through each Item and get to each payrecord and each field?

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry if this doesn't help, because your explanation is hard to follow.  But, I'll assume that you are saying that you have an object of type Payrecords, which contains references to seven other objects of types PNAR_OP, PNAR_RP, etc.  Each of these latter objects contain "20-30 fields" that you want to get at.  You ask how to loop through all of these.

A simple way to do that is to use an array.  Yes, you can foreach through Collections or (better yet) Dictionaries, but arrays work, they're easy to understand, and they were iterating through objects when Collections were running around in diapers.

Let your Payrecords have a property of type Object(6).  When you initialize it, instantiate one of each of the seven objects and add it to the array (for example, "Set myPayrecordsObjects(3) = New SubCCRRec" and so on).  To loop through, just use a for next loop to loop through the 7 objects.

Since you provide no information about how you structure your "fields" within these objects, I'll recommend that you iterate through the Fields collection of the ADO object to loop through those. (If you're not using the ADO Fields collection, well, your attention to detail gets mine in return.)

Comment: `Field` is a generic term for variable declared in a class - often a Property is used to provide access an underlying Field, without directly exposing the actual variable.